# WooCommerce REST API create order not including total tax price?

Tags: php, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api

I am trying to add tax amount to my WooCommerce REST API for creating new order but it's not working.

```
$order_data = [
    'payment_method' => 'COD',
    'payment_method_title' => 'Cash on delivery',
    'set_paid' => true,
    'line_items' => '1',
    'customer_id' => '1111',
    'total' => 250,
    'shipping_lines' => [
        [
            'method_id' => 'flat_rate',
            'method_title' => 'Flat Rate',
            'total' => 50
        ]
    ],
    'tax' => [
        'total_tax' => '100',
    ]
];



$data = $woocommerce->post('orders', $order_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

The attribute for tax is 'tax_lines' not 'tax' see: https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/v3.html#orders-properties

```
...
],   
'tax_lines' => [
    'total_tax' => '100',
]
```

Comment: Does this work? I see all fields as read-only in the api docs.

Answer (score 0):

`tax_lines` is a READ-ONLY property. See [here](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#order-tax-lines-properties).